# Loadrequest: in a Non-Visible UIWebView or load a webPage without using a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

Am need to download and cache an entire webPage before navigating to another screen. For caching I have sub classed `NSURLCache` and and saving the response by overriding  `cachedResponseForRequest:request` and `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` methods. It works and caches without any problems when There is webView and I load the request in it.

In my case I need to download many webPages before its actually displayed on a webView. So how do I simulate the `loadRequest:` of a UIWebView without actually adding it as a subView anywhere? or preferably any other way I can load a webpage without using a UIWebView at all..??

Here is what I discovered :

1. If the UIwebView is not added as subView, and if I call `loadRequest:`, the request doesn't load (not even delegate methods are called..!)
2. I tried with NSURLConnection,

   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlrequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
           }];

and also,

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlrequest delegate:nil];
if (theConnection) {

}
```

But the problem with the above approach is that, it only sends only one request, i mean it won't request for images,css and js files in the webPage which I need to cache.

So, what's the way to make it request everything just like in `UIWebView`'s `loadRequest`..??